# Is this possible to compress a JPEG file with zip libraries

Tags: c#, image, compression, zip, jpeg

As I know the jpeg file have a best compression ratio between another image extensions, and if I correct we can not more compress a jpeg file because that have best compression, so please help me about this. I create some jpegs as following:

```
ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
ImageCodecInfo ici = null;
foreach(ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs) {
if(codec.MimeType == "image/jpeg")
    ici = codec;
}
EncoderParameters ep = new EncoderParameters();
ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, _quality);

using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
     Bitmap capture = GetImage();
     capture.Save(ms, ici, ep);
  }
```

And I zipped them with sharpziplib, in average every jpeg size is 130KB and after zip every file compressed to about 70KB, how it possible? there is just 2 answer I can Imagine.

1- We can Compress Jpeg file with more compression ratio by zip libraries

2- My jpeg file not correctly created, and we can create better jpegs (with more compression ratio as we can not more compress them with zip libraries)

Does any one know about this? if we can create better jpegs please help me about it.

**Edit:**

this is my zip code to compress jpegs:

```
void addnewentry(MemoryStream stream, string pass,
                 string ZipFilePath, string entryname){

ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(ZipFilePath);

            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(pass))
                zf.Password = pass;

            StaticDataSource sds = new StaticDataSource(Stream);
            zf.BeginUpdate();
            zf.Add(sds, entryName);
            zf.CommitUpdate();
            zf.IsStreamOwner = true;
            zf.Close();
}

public class StaticDataSource : IStaticDataSource {

    public Stream stream { get; set; }

    public StaticDataSource() {
        this.stream.Position = 0; 
    }

    public StaticDataSource(Stream stream) {

            this.stream = stream;
            this.stream.Position = 0;
        }

    public Stream GetSource() {
            this.stream.Position = 0;
            return stream;

    }

}
```

Comment: Zip a JPEG using your choice of ZIP utility and it will have roughly the same size (if not greater) than the original JPEG. JPEG files are compressed already (though not using ZIP compression). Your gains will be minimal at best by zipping JPEGS.

Comment: JPEG images are already compressed. You're not going to gain anything by compressing them again.

Comment: @CodyGray So how can I compressed them? how can I create a jpeg that I can't compress more?

Comment: They're already compressed. You don't need to compress them. If you want a more highly compressed JPEG, then turn up the compression level setting in the library you're using to save the JPEG.

Comment: @Saeid - Just keep in mind that JPEG is lossly meaning the more it is compressed the lower quality the result.

Comment: @Saeid, can you post your compression code? Might you be saving alot of unused space after the end of your image data?

Comment: When you zip the image file with the built in Windows compression tool (Right click --> Send to --> compressed folder) or by other zip utility, do you get same results, or is it just by using SharpZipLib?

Comment: @ShadowWizard the result is almost same.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce what you describe, can you host sample image somewhere and post link?

Comment: @ShadowWizard that is not any special image, you can just print screen and save with paint in jpeg format.

Answer (score 3):

As most of people already stated, you can't compress such already compressed files further easily. Some people works hard on JPEG recompression (recompression = partially decoding already compressed file, and then compressing those data with a custom stronger model and entropy coder. Recompression usually ensures bit-identical results). Even that advanced recompression techniques, I only saw at most 25% improvement. [PackJPG](http://www.elektronik.htw-aalen.de/packjpg/) is one them. You can have a look at the other compressors [here](http://www.maximumcompression.com/data/jpg.php). As you realize, even top rank compressor couldn't reach exactly 25% (even though it's very complex).

Taking these facts into considerations, ZIP (actually deflate) cannot improve compression that much (it's a very old and inefficient if you compare it with top 10 compressors). I believe there are two possible reasons for that problem:

1. You're accidentally adding some extra data to JPEG stream (possibly adding after JPEG stream).
2. .NET outputs lots of redundant data to JFIF file. Maybe some big EXIF data and such.

To solve the problem, you can use a JFIF dump tool to observe what's inside the JFIF container. Also, you may want to try your JPEG files with PackJPG.

Comment: I also have a same result with capture screen by print screen button and save jpeg in paint. how you explain this one?

Comment: At first, I tought they were some photos which have smooth gradients. But, according to your "proof", I believe you're compressing artificial images (e.g. computer generated images, desktop screenshots, charts etc.). If that's the case, then it's no wonder you can compress it further. Because, JPEG leave a considerable amount of entropy for such images. And that can be further reduced by simple programs. To prove what I mean, just create a huge white image with Paint and save it as JPEG. Then compress that file with a ZIP compressor (especially 7-zip MAX setting). You'll be amazed :)

Answer (score 2):

The JPEG compression algorithm has two stages: a "lossy" stage where visual elements that should be imperceptible to the human eye are removed, and a "lossless" stage where the remaining data is compressed using a technique called Huffmann coding. After Huffmann coding, further lossless compression techniques (like ZIP) will not reduce the size of the image file by significant amount.

However, if you were to zip multiple copies of the same small image together, the ZIP ("DEFLATE") algorithm will recognise the repetition of data, and exploit it to reduce the total file size to less than the sum of the individual files' size. This may be what you're seeing in your experiment.

Stated very simply, losless compression techniques like Huffman coding (part of JPEG) and DEFLATE (used in ZIP) try to discover repeated patterns in your original data, and then represent those repeated patterns using shorter codes.

In short, you won't be able to really improve JPEG by adding on another lossless compression stage.

Comment: FYI, ZIP != LZW. Zip generally uses deflate not LZW.

Comment: according your answer I take a test, at first I zipped one jpeg file the original size is 99KB and the compressed size is 69KB with (31% ratio), So I zipped 15 jpeg files that are really similar (take capture screen repeatedly) average of original size is 99KB and all of them compressed by 31% ratio to average of 69KB, So I think there is another describe about it.

Comment: With a small file like that, chances are that you're seeing exactly what @DanielS is describing in the other answer. The JPEG container allows you to store extra information about the image outside the compressed contents (the EXIF data). Depending on the program/camera used to create the image, and the size of the image itself, it could be a fairly large amount of uncompressed data. You can either strip this information out of the image using an EXIF editing tool or library if you don't need it. If you do need lots of EXIF data, zipping the JPEGs together might not be a bad idea after all.

Answer (score 2):

No one has mentioned that fact that JPEG is merely a container. There are many compression methods that can be used with that file format (JFIF, JPEG-2000, JPEG-LS, etc.) Further compressing that file can yield varying results depending on the content.
Also, some cameras store huge amounts of EXIF data (sometimes resulting in about 20K of data) and that might account for the difference you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

You can *attempt* to compress anything with zlib. You just don't always get a reduction in size.

Usually compressing a whole jpeg file will yield a handful of bytes savings as it will compress the [jpeg header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure) (including any plain text comments or [EXIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) data)

This may not fully account for the 40K of compression you see unless you have a huge amount of header data or your jpeg data somehow winds up with alot of repeating values inside.

Comment: but I think my zipped files is more than just header zip, 130KB to 70KB, you say this is just header compression?

Answer (score 0):

**Zipping JPEGs reduces size because**: EXIF data isn't compressed, JPEG is optimized for photos and not GIF-like data, and compressing files creates a single data stream, allowing patterns across multiple files and removing the requirement that each must be aligned with a specific block on disk. The latter can alone save around 4KB per compressed file.

**The main problem with zipping pre-compressed images** is that it requires extra work (human and CPU) for prep and viewing, which may not be worth the effort (unless you have millions of images that are infrequently accessed, or some kind of automated image service you're developing).

**A better approach is to minimize the native file size**, forgetting zip. There are many free libraries and apps out there to help with this. For example, [ImageOptim](https://imageoptim.com/) combines several libs into one (OptiPNG, PNGCrush, Zopfli, AdvPNG, Gifsicle, PNGOUT), for a barrage of aggressive tricks to minimize size. Works great for PNGs; haven't tried it much with JPEGs.

Though remember that with any compression, there's always a point of diminishing returns. It's up to you to decide whether or not a few extra bytes really matter in the long run.